# createElement is giving error in Manifest V3 of chrome extension

Tags: chrome, extension

Now I am trying to migrate from `manifest v2` to `manifest v3` of chrome extension.
I followed steps from here https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/migrate/checklist.
But keep to showing `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createElement')`
Thank you in advance!